# Excluding hidden files in locate

Tags: command-line, bash, search, regex, locate

We have a Ubuntu NAS sharing SMB and Netatalk with some Macs and I often use `locate` to find my files. Unfortunately since installing Netatalk it has written tons of `.AppleDouble` cache files to share with AFP faster (I assume) and my `locate` prints all of that information. I'm constantly using `cp` on files only to find I've copied a useless hidden file on accident.

I have been using `locate -i filename | fgrep -v ".AppleDouble" | fgrep -v "._"` to remove those hidden files, but I'd like to change my `bashrc` in such a way that this is more or less default.

What is the most effective way to exclude hidden files from what locate prints? With regex? Right now, I would write a script that passes an argument to locate and pipes to grep as shown, but if there's an easier way, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

To exclude hidden files when using locate, try this:

```
locate -i --regex "^/absolute/path/to/the/directory/[^\.]+"
```

If the directory contains files like `.hidden`, `..hidden`, `...hiden` they will be excluded too. If you just want to exclude only `.hidden`, remove the `+` from the end:

```
locate -i --regex "^/absolute/path/to/the/directory/[^\.]"
```

or simply (extended regexp is not needed too):

```
locate -ir "^/absolute/path/to/the/directory/[^\.]"
```

**EDIT:** After editing the question, the whole meaning of the question is different now and my initial answer is not correct in the modified context. Run the following to exclude all hidden files from the Output of `locate` (given the filename does not contain `/`):

```
locate -i "file_name" | egrep -v "/(\.)+[^/]+$"
```

Comment: Somewhat helpful, but I am often using locate because it searches so many directories so quickly. If I was only searching in one it would probably be easier for me to use `find .` which plays pretty nice with regex and arguments.

Comment: This is what you wanted, right? using `locate` to find files without the hidden ones? If not, please clarify a bit more.

Comment: Forgive me if I wasn't clear enough--I may edit my question. I'm trying to figure out a way to exclude hidden files from what locate prints. As if there was a "ignore hidden files" flag in the program I could use.

Comment: After your edit, the whole meaning of the question is different now and my initial answer is wrong in the modified context. You would be better to ask it as a new question..

Comment: @ezgoodnight: Please check my edits..

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, but the regex you've added seems to be only printing directories. I get the result I want with `locate "filename.ext" | fgrep -v "/."`

Comment: Did you try `locate -i "file_name" | egrep -v "(\.)+[^/]+$"`? If your filename does not contain `/` then this should work..Also `locate` looks for files only..

Comment: Just copied and pasted that and got only directories when I should be getting tons of .jpg files.

Comment: I see, try this `locate -i "file_name" | egrep -v "/(\.)+[^/]+$"`

Comment: Also `locate "filename.ext" | fgrep -v "/."` will fail in cases where a hidden directory contains `filename.ext` ..